# Returning first element of a double linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I have made a Node and Deque class to represent a double linked list. I wrote a function to return the first item in the linked list, but was getting an IndexError - an error that I have raised in my code in case the linked list is empty.

My expected output:

```
my_list.push_front(1)
my_list.push_front(2)
my_list.push_front(3)
linked list is [3, 2, 1]
print(my_list.peek_front()) --> 3
```

My linked list function file:

```
class Node:
    """
    Initialize empty node
    """
    def __init__(self, data=None, prev = None, next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
        self.prev = prev

class Deque:
    """
    A double-ended queue
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes an empty Deque
        """
        self.head = Node()

    def push_front(self, e): #should work fine
        """
        Inserts an element at the front of the Deque
        :param e: An element to insert
        """
        new_head = Node(data = e, next = self.head)

        if self.head:
            self.head.prev = new_head
        self.head = new_head

    def peek_front(self): #FUNCTION WITH ERROR
        """
        Looks at, but does not remove, the first element
        :return: The first element
        """
        if self.head.data == None: #if it is empty, raise error
            raise IndexError
        else:
            return self.head.data

    def listprint(self, node):
        """
        Prints each element of the node front to back
        :param node:
        """
        while (node is not None):
            print(node.data)
            last = node
            node = node.next
```

My main file:

```
def main():

    my_list = Deque()

    my_list.push_front(1)
    my_list.push_front(2)
    my_list.push_front(3)

    my_list.listprint(my_list.head) #print elements in the list
    print(my_list.peek_front())
```

My error message:

```
IndexError (error that was unintentionally raised by me)
```

Comment: Not getting your error. However, it does list a "None" at the end of the listprint, which should not be surprising: What your `__init__` creates is not an empty deque but rather a deque with a single node that has empty data. Maybe that's your way of implementing an empty deque (not a good idea if you ask me), but then you shouldn't be surprised that this empty-data node persists as you add new stuff onto the deque (after all, you never remove it).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you for your input. How could I get rid of the single node that has empty data at the end of my linked list? And were you able to successfully print the first element of the linked list with my function if you did not get the error?

Comment: I'd replace `self.head = Node()` by `self.head = None` in the `__init__`, and `if self.head.data == None` by `if self.head is None` in the `peek_front` (note: `is None` is better Python than `== None`, since the identity check is enough and the equality check involves indirection). I *think* the rest should work, but I haven't checked.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks it worked! If you want, you can write as an answer format and I'll be happy to accept for rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not getting your error (and I tried on python2 and python3, though out of laziness I just ran it as scripts without `def main()`).

However, the output lists a `None` at the end of the listprint:

```
$ python test.py
3
2
1
None
3
```

This is because what your `__init__` creates is not an empty deque but rather a deque with a single node that has empty data. Maybe that's your way of implementing an empty deque (not a good idea if you ask me), but then you shouldn't be surprised that this empty-data node persists as you add new stuff onto the deque (after all, you never remove it).

If you want to fix this behavior, replace `self.head = Node()` by `self.head = None` in the `__init__`, and replace `if self.head.data == None` by `if self.head is None` in the `peek_front` (note: `is None` is better Python than `== None`, since the identity check is enough and the equality check involves indirection). I think the rest should work, but I haven't checked.